# C#.Net Check if 'Process' has a gui

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, process

Is there any way to check if a variable of type `Process` currently has an opened GUI/window.

I'm using this to try and get all open application (with an open GUI) and then render their icons

Comment: `Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero).ToArray();`. You may want to use the WMI's [Win32_Process class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process), though.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this.

After a bit a research, I came across the following article in [UserInteractive Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.userinteractive?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Environment_UserInteractive.)

So maybe you can try something like this:

```
Environment.UserInteractive
```

The above property is a boolean, which returns true if the current process is running in user interactive mode

And also you can look on this article: [MainWindowHandle Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_MainWindowHandle)

which gets the window handle of the main window of the associated process, especially `IntPtr` which is the system-generated window handle of the main window of the associated process.